# Formatting for algebraic expressions

Tags: python, expression, indentation, algebra

Here is my code to solve for this equation manually:

```
b=2
c=3
sum= [[1, 4 + c, 0], [6, 2 + b + c, b]]
[[1, 7, 0], [6, 7, 2]]
```

this is the output I get and it works and the type : <class 'list'>

How do I get the same output but as a string? I don't want to change the above list type   to string.

```
b=2
c=3
sum= "[[1, 4 + c, 0], [6, 2 + b + c, b]]"
'[[1, 4 + c, 0], [6, 2 + b + c, b]]'
```

Why does this not work, it is the right output "type" but the values for b and c don't work.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty easy to do. You can use `eval()` to evaluate python expressions. From the documentation, for `eval`, `the source may be a string representing a Python expression or a code object as returned by compile()`. If I understood you correctly, you need to use for strings.

For example,

```
>>> b=2
>>> c=3
>>> sum= "[[1, 4 + c, 0], [6, 2 + b + c, b]]"
>>> result=eval(sum)
>>> result
[[1, 7, 0], [6, 7, 2]]
```

If you want to convert it to string, simply do `result=str(eval(sum))`.

Comment: Thanks, this works beautifully and solves my problem

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lambda` or in other words use function `def`
NOTE: don't use `sum` as a variable name, because it is a built-in function in python.

```py
b=2
c=3
sum_ = lambda b,c: [[1, 4 + c, 0], [6, 2 + b + c, b]]
sum_(b,c)
```

```
[[1, 7, 0], [6, 7, 2]]
```

Comment: Good point, I will choose my variable names more wisely.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
sum = f"[[1, {4 + c}, 0], [6, {2 + b + c}, b]]"
```

Or this:

```
sum = str([[1, 4 + c, 0], [6, 2 + b + c, b]])
```

Or even this ([not very recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice)):

```
sum = eval("[[1, 4 + c, 0], [6, 2 + b + c, b]]")
```